# Play is asynchronous or non-blocking framework

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, playframework, akka, nonblocking

I have read several tutorials and everywhere play is mentioned as "Non-Blocking". I am confused that by saying non-blocking do they mean asynchronous or non-blocking I/O.

As per my understanding when any http request is received on play server then it assigns a dedicated thread for processing that request and holds that thread till it returns a response. So how it is non-blocking?

Also by asynchronous do they mean that main thread can spawn a new thread and delegate its work to it and run next statement? (For that we need to use akka)

Comment: Well, it does not assign a dedicated thread. Where did you read that?

Comment: I am using play in my project and what I observed while working is that unless response is not returned that Thread is waiting. We are making a call to external service and until that external service gives response Thread remains blocked.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, you need to understand how Futures in scala work. Futures do not stop the execution of the program. All futures are non-blocking. I would suggest you read up on this : http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html.

Since play's asynchronous library is built on top of Scala's Futures. Once you're done with that, you will have enough knowledge to answer your own question. Also, read this if you need more information about how futures are used in play :

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAsync